# Exclude words but include characters in regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
<Chord: Aaug>, <Chord: C#aug/A>, <Chord: Faug/A>
```

I want to extract the chord names, what is between `<Chord:` and `>` and also include the commas. So, for that string, I want to match `Aaug, C#aug/A, Faug/A`.

I have tried this regex: `\b(?:(?!Chord:)\w)+\b`. This excludes the word `Chord`, but does not match `#` and `/`.

Comment: Use `<Chord:([^>]*)>` as regex for `re.findall`

Comment: Maybe `", ".join(re.findall(r'<Chord:\s*([^>]*)>', text))`?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aBJdM2/1

Comment: Thank you all, I settled for `chords = re.findall(r'<Chord: ([^>]*)', str(note_to_chord(notes_pressed_char)))
                text = ", ".join(chords)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and test in link [demo of regex](https://regex101.com/r/tTubhP/1)

```
<Chord:([^>]*)>
```

***Explanation:*** From `<Chord:` till 1st occurrence of `>` along with `>` matching it, if you want to match all occurrences in python, you could use `findall` of `re` library in python3.

***With python demo:***

To catch values between each `<Chord:` to `>` try:

```
import re
a='<Chord: Aaug>, <Chord: C#aug/A>, <Chord: Faug/A>'
re.findall(r'<Chord: ([^>]*)', a)
['Aaug', 'C#aug/A', 'Faug/A']
```

OR to match values with `<Chord:` and `>`:

```
import re
a='<Chord: Aaug>, <Chord: C#aug/A>, <Chord: Faug/A>'
re.findall(r'<Chord:([^>]*)>', a)
[' Aaug', ' C#aug/A', ' Faug/A']
re.findall(r'<Chord:[^>]*>', a)
['<Chord: Aaug>', '<Chord: C#aug/A>', '<Chord: Faug/A>']
```

***To access individual items from list:***

```
re.findall(r'<Chord:[^>]*>', a)[0]
'<Chord: Aaug>'
re.findall(r'<Chord:[^>]*>', a)[1]
'<Chord: C#aug/A>'
```